# Why are unboxed arrays not an instance of foldable?

Tags: arrays, haskell

Figuring out the correct data container to use can be a bit tricky in Haskell,  for my 2D grid application I thought using `UArray` would be appropriate. However, as far as I can tell `UArray` is not an instance of `foldable` (not in `Data.Array.IArray` nor `Data.Array.Unboxed`).

Is there a reason for this? I can make my own helper functions but the absence of a `foldable` instance suggests that maybe I shouldn't.

Comment: At least with GHC, `Array` is defined in `base` in `GHC.Arr`. The `array` package reexports this type. The `Foldable` instance is defined in [`Data.Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html), not by the array module. However, `UArray` is defined in `Data.Array.Base` in the `array` package. `array` itself does not define `Foldable` instance at all as far as I can see.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what is happening under the hood, but it seems like the `Data.Array.IArray` package contains the `Foldable` instance for the `Array` type, whether or not it is actually coded there. It seems silly that this does not also provide an instance for the `UArray` type if there is one available. Is it an oversight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe such an instance is impossible, because it requires an extra constraint in the data type contained by the array, which cannot be expressed in Foldable. In mono-traversable, I do define MonoFoldable instances for unboxed and storable vectors.

**EDIT**: To be clear, the constraint I'm referring to is that all functions in `Data.Vector.Unbox` only work if the value contained by the `Vector` is an instance of `Unbox`, whereas `Foldable` requires that `foldMap`, `foldr`, etc, are defined for *all* possible types (as is the case for types like lists, boxed vectors, etc). There is no way with the `Foldable` typeclass to state "the contained value must meet these constraints." With `MonoFoldable`, there is.

Comment: Ah, because having an array of a certain type doesn't imply that type is actually sensible (there's no way to figure out the size)? Whereas with `vector`, the element type determines the vector type?

Comment: Could you explain more about what this constraint could be? Are you saying that I cannot define a fold function for unboxed arrays?

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, it seems that to be a foldable instance, at minimum the class needs a definition for `foldMap` and `foldr`. I don't see why these can't be defined for an unboxed array.

Comment: I've added a fuller explanation of what constraints I mean. @dfeuer It's simply not possible in Haskell's type system to write inside a `Foldable` instance `foldr = Data.Vector.Unbox.foldr`, since the type of the lhs is does not have the `Unbox a` constraint.

Comment: Urk. The reasons for unboxed arrays and unboxed vectors look a bit different. But I'm beginning to see what you mean. I think `MonoFoldable` is probably just *better* than `Foldable` in many ways.

Comment: (Except it should have been `class e ~ Element c => MonoFoldable e c` to make constraints using it nicer.)

Comment: It's a trade-off. Since most cases don't have constraints, `MonoFoldable` went for the simpler usage for the common case. `MonoFoldable` is strictly more powerful than `Foldable`, and I prefer using it in all cases. (On the other hand, `MonoFunctor` and `MonoTraversable` are significantly weaker than their polymorphic counterparts.)

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman, So clarify, a foldable instance of UArray cannot be defined because the instance definition cannot contain the constraints required by the unboxed variables? Is this considered a limitation of the Haskell language?

Comment: Your claudication is correct. I'd say it's a limitation of the definition of Foldable, not Haskell. After all, MonoFoldable handles this case just fine.

Comment: What I mean is that `MonoFoldable Int c => ...` is a lot more pleasant than `(MonoFoldable c, Element c ~ Int) => ...`.