# Why is it impossible to Applicative-traverse arrays? (Or is it?)

Tags: performance, haskell, monads, unboxing

While pondering how to best map, i.e. `traverse`, an `a -> Maybe a`-Kleisli over an [unboxed vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#t:Vector), I looked for an existing implementation. Obviously `U.Vector` is not `Traversable`, but [it does supply a `mapM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#g:22), which for `Maybe` of course works just fine.

But the question is: is the `Monad` constraint really needed? Well, it turns out that even [boxed vectors cheat for the `Traversable` instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Vector.html#line-427): they really just traverse a *list*, which they convert from/to:

```
instance Traversable.Traversable Vector where
  {-# INLINE traverse #-}
  traverse f xs = Data.Vector.fromList Applicative.<$> Traversable.traverse f (toList xs)
```

`mono-traversable` [does the same thing also for unboxed vectors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.1/docs/src/Data-MonoTraversable.html#line-998); here this seems even more gruesome performance-wise.

Now, I wouldn't be surprised if `vector` was actually able to fuse many of these hacked traversals into a far more efficient form, but still – there seems to be a fundamental problem, preventing us from implementing a traversal on an array right away. Is there any “deep reason” for this inability?

Comment: The lack of the instance for `U.Vector` has to do with the `Unbox` constraint on the elements. See [*Why are unboxed arrays not an instance of foldable?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36322904/2751851) (the answer, by Snoyman, also includes some relevant comments about *mono-traversable*).

Comment: Sure, but that's not what I'm asking about. I don't need an actual `Traversable` instance, I just need an efficient traversal! And `mono-traversable` doesn't offer this.

Comment: Oops -- I didn't notice the "obviously" in your first paragraph :)

Comment: Hmm... If it fuses reliably then I suppose there's not much incentive to look for a different--presumably harder, if not impossible--solution.

Comment: There seems to be an implicit assumption here that the `Traversable` instances for records with many fields are "efficient" in some sense. In fact I wouldn't be surprised if traversing a 100-element vector (with the above implementation that converts to and from lists) was cheaper than the derived instance for a record with 100 fields, at least for certain monads.

Comment: @ReidBarton aha... whence do you infer that implicit assumption? I didn't have any thought about records with many fields here.

Comment: Well I guess I don't understand the question. It's obviously possible to traverse an array, since the code you pasted does it. There must be some other constraint... but what?

Comment: @ReidBarton traversing without creating an intermediate list, for example? Mutable arrays + `unsafeDupablePerformIO` + `unsafeFreeze` could do it, I think.

Comment: @ReidBarton on a second though, it's no good, for example we can't use destructive update when we traverse in the list applicative.

Answer (score 2):

After reading through the relevant source of `vector` and trying to make `mapM` work with `Applicative` I think the reason why `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector` doesn't have a `traverse :: (Applicative f, Unbox a, Unbox b) -> (a -> f b) -> Vector a -> f (Vector b)` function and `Data.Vector.Vector` doesn't have a native `traverse` is the fusion code. The offender is the following `Stream` type:

```
-- Data/Vector/Fusion/Stream/Monadic.hs  Line: 137

-- | Result of taking a single step in a stream
data Step s a where
  Yield :: a -> s -> Step s a
  Skip  :: s -> Step s a
  Done  :: Step s a

-- | Monadic streams
data Stream m a = forall s. Stream (s -> m (Step s a)) s
```

This is used internally to implement `mapM`. The `m` will be the same as from your initial call to `Data.Vector.Unboxed.mapM`. But because the spine of this stream is inside the `m` functor, it is not possible to work with it if you only have an applicative for `m`.

See also this issue on the `vector` GitHub repo: [Weaken constraint on mapM](https://github.com/haskell/vector/issues/132).

Disclaimer: I don't really know how fusion works. I don't know how `vector` works.